# Can I create dynamic variable names in jade using an array of string values for an object?

Tags: javascript, pug

I have an array of values named `values`. I have an `each` statement that I am iterating through the array. Within the `each` statement I am using a for loop to iterate through an array of objects. When I iterate through the objects I want to check and see if they have a `true` boolean variable that shares the name of the items in my values array.

```
- var values = ["u10","u11","u14","u17","u18"];
  each val in values.length ? values : ['There are no values']
    -for obj in objects
      if obj.val == true
        [do something here]
```

My if statement is currently not working. Does anyone know how to write this if statement in Jade? Each object has a boolean variable that corelates to the values in the list. A model for the objects looks like so:

```
{"object":{
   "u10":true,
   "u11":false,
   "u14":true,
   "u17":false,
   "u18":true
  }
}
```

If I write the if statement with the hardcoded variable name such as

```
if obj.u10 == true
```

it works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`obj.val` will literally look for a property named `"val"` on the object `obj`, as if `obj = {val: true}` were the object.

What you need is **`obj[val]`** which will interpolate the variable `val`'s actual *value* and use that to look up that property name